# How to get what the runner name is inside the github actions workflow?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api, runner

I have a github actions workflow which contains below snippets.

```
runs-on:
  - ubuntu-latest
  - some-self-hosted-runner
```

Is there a way to get the value of runner like `ubuntu-latest` or `some-self-hosted-runner` inside the workflow so that I can conditionally branch the steps using if, else blocks?

I did try to get `runner.os`. But it's not giving the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [matrix](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-a-matrix-for-your-jobs) for scenarios like this, such as having multiple runners, needing to run different combinations etc.

```
jobs:
  <job-name>:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest, some-self-hosted-runner]
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    steps:
      - name: check os
        run: echo ${{ matrix.os }}
```